# DBT - write dbt test --store-failures to a specific table in my data warehouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, dbt

Good afternoon,
I want to write the *dbt test* values to a specific table in my data warehouse.
I have tested multiple schema inclusions in all the possible .yml files and I am not really finding the correct place to specify to which database I want the tests to be recorded.
Nowadays, it always answers me with the error of not having the permissions to perform a *glue:CreateDatabase* action, which in fact is not what I want to do, but rather write to table specified by me.
To conclude, what I am asking here is **how can I specify where the dbt tests results are being written, instead of letting dbt create and store the values in the default schemas?**
If somebody could help me on this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I have went through all the docs in dbt and there is no specific example about it, they say it is possible, but I could only specify it for the creation of the models no for writing the tests

Answer (score 4):

Well, I managed to fix it, I was almost throwing my computer away, because I didn't have more air to pull off, but basically we can specify the target database in the dbt_project.yml. To do that, just add to the dbt_project.yml

```
tests:
  +store_failures: true
  +schema: "path that you want"
```

I did not find any information in dbt documentation, neither community forums, so it was just an iterative process of testing possible approaches

Comment: The relevant docs are here: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/schema#tests. I agree that's a little hard to find and it should be referenced on https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/store_failures also. You could open a PR!

Comment: I disagree that it should be referenced on the `store_failures` page, since that is a separate resource config from `schema`. I think this is a case of just being impatient and not reading the docs thoroughly. If developing tests, you should be familiar with the tests config pages before starting.

Comment: [Test-configs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/test-configs#general-configurations) has the note `# relevant for store_failures only` that links to [store_failures](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/store_failures). Really wish store_failures would link back to test-config. The only way I figured out how to use the store_failures feature was thanks to this stackoverflow post!

Comment: @NathanGriffiths It's not in a test config page, this is the "schema" config page. Oh the irony about calling others impatient and not reading carefully.

Comment: @Seub I'm well aware of which pages are being referred to and by "tests config pages" I am referring to all resource config documentation pages relevant to tests, not a _test config page_.  Irony indeed. To reiterate, it is not necessary to duplicate the information regarding store_failures schema from https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/schema#tests to https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/store_failures since they already linked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add schema but it only created the tables under the new schema, and it makes sense, need to write some macro for it.